# asp.net mvc and canonical link: bug?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, canonical-link

I created a simple CMS in asp.net MVC. Every article has a [canonical link](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html), which I want to use in my master page like this:

```
<link href="<%= Model.CanonicalLink %>" rel="canonical" />
```

However, when I view the source of this page in Firefox, it shows me:

```
<link href="../../Views/Shared/%3C%25=%20Model.CanonicalLink%20%25%3E" rel="canonical" />
```

I must be very stupid, or it is a bug. When I move the 
    <%= Model.CanonicalLink %> 
part out of the `<link />` then it shows me the canonical link. So, what is causing this odd behaviour?

Comment: What is the type of `Model.CanonicalLink` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the ASPX parser stomping on your HTML.  Remove the **runat="server"** from the `<head>` element in which this `<link>` is defined.